# How do I override the malicious software check for the SDL2 framework on mac?

Tags: c, macos, sdl-2

I have installed the official [release](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.28.4) of SDL2 from the releases section of the repo.
Despite having followed the instructions in the README.txt and installing it into `/Library/Frameworks`, I get the following error when running a basic "Hello World" application:

> “SDL2.framework” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Naturally, everything online says to just open the app using the context menu by Ctrl+clicking on it, but that doesn't work in my case. I think this is because it's not the app that can't be verified, but rather the framework.

I also tried `codesign -f -s - /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2`, but this seemed to have no effect.

How do I bypass or otherwise override this warning for the SDL2 framework?

For reference, here's the example code to test the installation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

int main()
{
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
        {
                printf("failed to initialize SDL\n");
                return 1;
        }

        printf("Hello, SDL!\n");
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
}
```

I built it like so:

```
clang main.c -o hello -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but I go into my anti-virus (AV) settings and exclude all my project coding directories(folders).  Else AV wreaks havoc when my compiler is creating all these files at compile time, and the AV is getting frantic -- trying to check them all -- interfering with my compiler's file write actions, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491#:%7E:text=If%20you%27re%20certain%20that,security%20settings%20to%20open%20it.&text=Go%20to%20Security%20%26%20Privacy.,open%20or%20install%20the%20app.).
I had to open the Privacy & Security settings, then go to "developer tools" and whitelist applications that were allowed to launch "insecure" apps.
I chose to whitelist the terminal and VS Code.